# Clone RAID 1 array to single HDD - Linux (OpenSuse)

Tags: ssd, clone, opensuse, raid-1, clonezilla

I have a server with a hardware made RAID 1 array (Adaptec board). The array is composed of 2 SSD and the OS id OpenSuse Linux.
I want to clone the array on a single SSD and make it bootable.
I managed to clone one of the ssds with Clonezilla, but it doesn't boot. It sees the boot menu and the kernel version, but gives an error after: could not find /dev/root, want me to fail back to /dev/disc/by -id/scsi-SAdaptec_SYSTEM-part2?
What's interesting is that I managed to start the image made with Clonezilla on a virtual machine (in VirtualBox) but it doesn't work on the PC. What do you advise me to do?

Comment: You do not want to clone the physical drives data, but the "emulated" drive provided by the RAID controller. Check `lsblk` to identify it.